# Why do I get a segment fault in my C function that reverses the order of words in a string?

Tags: c

This is my function that is supposed to flip a string such as "Today is a beautiful day"
into "day beautiful a is Today" My nextword function (inside flipstring function) return the index of the beginning of every word in the string and also places '\0' after the word. When I use the function is get the error, segmentation fault (core dumped) and I can't figure out why.

```
void flip(char *str)
{
  // reverse the order of the words                                                                
  char buf[256];
  int i[2],k,j=0,c=0;

  //set k to the index of the first word in str 
  k = nextword(str);

  //Create an array (i) of the index of the beginning of every word
  //nextword also places a '\0' after every word in str
  while ( k != -1)
    {

      i[j] = k;
      j++;
      k = nextword(NULL);
    }

  //place each word in buf in reverse order
  //replace the eos with a space  
  for ( j=j-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--)    //starts with index of last word in string str
    {
     buf[c]=str[i[j]];
           while(buf[c]!='\0')
             {
           c++;
           buf[c]=str[i[j]+c];
          }

       buf[c] = ' ';  //replaces '\0' after every word with a space
       c=c+1;
    } 
  buf[c] = '\0';  //Places eos at the end of the string in buf
   printf("%s\n",buf[0]);

}
```

Call it,

```
void main(void)
{
  char str[] = "Today is a beautiful day!\t\n";
  flip(str);
  //printf("%s",str);
}
```

Comment: What is `nextword`? Please post full code.

Comment: and post how you call it and what you pass.

Comment: -1 for not telling where the segfault occurs

Comment: You're not supposed to delete the question after it has been answered.

Comment: Do *not* destroy your questions by editing the content out. The purpose of this site is not to help you, it's to provide a *reference* to future users with the same problem. By attempting to destroy your question, you're taking from this site without contributing anything to the other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `printf("%s\n",buf[0]);` you're passing a character to printf instead of a string which will cause a segmentation fault. Use `printf("%s\n", buf);` instead.

Also you aren't copying the words correctly, in `buf[c]=str[i[j]+c];` c is not the offset from the beginning of the current word but from the beginning of buf, you should use another counter to use as the offset.

```
l = 0;
while(buf[c]!='\0'){
   c++;
   l++;
   buf[c]=str[i[j]+l];
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I just have to figure out why my str is completely messed up and I am getting undesired results, lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this instruction:

```
buf[c]=str[i[j]+c];
```

c is a counter that is initialized in 0 at the very beginning of your function, and you are mixing the use of this counter to set the position of buf and to set the position of str.  This instruction is odd and it's posible that it may cause your segmentation fault.

Try to use 2 different counters, 1 for buf and one for str.

Comment: The error lied in my printf usage. I tried to pass a character instead of a string. Your answer may solve my other issue, which is a scrambled up string result.